# Cell Seperator Overlapping After Deleting A Cell with Dynamic Height

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using different heights for different cells in my table view. When I try to delete a cell by using swipe to delete, although I try to call `reloadTable` or begin/end updates, some of my cell separators overlaps with my bigger or smaller cells.

I guess that is because that the tableView is calculating height for only the visible rows. So that I tried to redisplay every cell manually by using `setNeedsRedisplay`, it did not work again.

I wonder what I can use to fully reload my cells, and change the cellHeights considering one less (deleted) `indexPath`. So that my bigger cells do not overlap with the smaller ones.

Btw. I also remove the cell content from my `dataSource` array.

Comment: how do you setup your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: , maybe it's actually reusing wrong cell.

Comment: If you are asking for a specific part I can post here but the whole method is too big, because I have a bunch of different cells, for loading, lazy loading, expanding not expanding e.g. But I have two different identifiers which are ?


    NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"feedLoadingCell";
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"feedCell";

Feed cell is always in 122pixel height but the other one changes according to the text inside, or loaded pictures inside. I deque if the cell will have any background picture or loading phase.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem at this address, if somebody else faces it:

http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/03/hide-uitableview-empty-cell-separator.html